# Syntax for SharePoint 2010 BCS URL Action to populate New form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, query-string, bcs

Have seen several posts with solutions for native SharePoint lists, including the very useful SPUtility.js (only for native SharePoint lists). But nothing to pass a value from a BCS list to a new BCS list. The Query string filter will not connect on the New form (no web part to connect it to) and does me no good on the lists page (already have that working).

A "go write custom code for everything" is not a solution for me.

There should be a way to 1) pass the value in the URL (ideal - what's the syntax?) or 2) make some other simple change, perhaps to the select list for the item -- I just can't find it. Have seen quite a few posts with similar questions. The Microsoft documentation is not useful and there are more questions on the "social" topics than answers.

Here's what I have:

I have a BCS list (sends item) tied to a BCS related list (receives item).

I have an action on the related list (ECT) to create a new item. Works fine with no parameters. I get a blank new form. The new form allows me to enter two items and choose two items (exactly as intended).

What I would like to have is the necessary ?something=something string so that my user does not have to select one of the choice items (MNumber - set as a key / required value)

User selects "New" from Actions. 
Form Opens
MNumber is automatically filled in based on the MNumber of the current item displayed in the BCS related list.

1. The string I supply is accepted. Does nothing. 
   /intake/Lists/ContactsList/NewForm.aspx
   /intake/Lists/ContactsList/NewForm.aspx?MNumber=1234
2. The string I supply is rejected - cannot be saved or insufficient values. 
   /intake/Lists/ContactsList/NewForm.aspx?MHICNumber={$MHICNumber}

Have also tried passing a string to one of the text fields (instead of the select field). Can't get that to work either. I've spent quite a few hours with the various boards. Nothing helpful.

Would also be nicer if I could set the New form to display in a pop-over window (as it does when I select New from the list view). Opening a new browser window is hokey and replacing the existing one is a navigation pain for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have this working ... Thanks to Kit Menke!

Created an Action on the External Content Type in the BCS....

```
/intake/Lists/ContactsList/NewForm.aspx?IDnumber={0}&Source=/intake/scheduling.aspx
```

where

parameter property 0 is the IDNumber from the ECT

The NewForm.aspx was edited to add a hidden content editor web part with references to three scripts Kit wrote - two supporting and one that sets the values.

```
http://site/list/NewForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2
```

1. User selects the Action on the displayed ECT list
2. Action uses the URL to go to the New page with the data
3. Kit's script adds the data to the form and puts in the date and time.

Note: The ID field needs to be a text field. Cannot be a selection list.